# Как сделать, чтобы border в input был сплошным белым?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

И как обращать к разным `<input>`, чтобы менять текст по умолчанию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю, как убрать это переход в `border`:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    font-size: 13pt;
    color:  #E7E7E7;
    font-family: Courier New;
}
```

Я нашла, как обращаться и  задавать конкретно ко всем стиль, текст по умолчанию, а вот к конкретному `<input>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте, или может быть идея прийдет, после моего примера

```css
label {
  display: block;
  color: white;
}
input {
  border: 5px solid #E7E7E7;/*Цвет Границы(border)*/
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #777; /*Цвет текстового поля*/
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; /*Закругляем уголки*/

}
input::placeholder {
  color: white;
}
label, input {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
form {
  width: 50%;
}

body {
  background: #777;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  
  <div>
    <input id="school" name="schoo" type="text" placeholder="Input">
  </div>
```